# Prove that $\sum _{k=0}^{n}{{(-1)}^{k}{\binom n k}}=0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Prove that:
$$\sum _{k=0}^{n}{{(-1)}^{k}\binom n k}=0$$

I tried with induction and failed.

A solution explain would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are many solutions at the link in my comment above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Binomial Theorem](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Binomial_Theorem) says  $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{0\le r\le n}\binom nr a^{n-r}b^r$$

for real or complex $a, b$, and non-negative integer $n$.

Put $a=1,b=-1$